# How to use Geometry Nodes to move objects in a collection?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm a bit desperate because I can't find a solution online after a long search. I hope to get help here.

I want to create a construction animation - with all objects in a certain collection.

That means:
I have a few objects in a collection and would like to animate them automatically via geometry nodes so that the objects fall down from above (Z-axis) one after the other (to their final location) after a set time.

Who can help me get started?

Many thanks in advance.

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with this node tree:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]